# Convert string to variable name in VBScript

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic, type-conversion

How can I convert a string to a variable name in VBscript? I found similar Q/A for [JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5613834/convert-string-to-variable-name-in-javascript), [C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7143120/convert-string-to-variable-name-or-variable-type), [Pyton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13002530/python-3-convert-string-to-variable), [Perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38587705/how-to-convert-raw-string-to-variable-variable-variable), [Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4633764/convert-string-to-variable-name-in-ruby), [Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8631935/creating-a-variable-name-using-a-string-value), but not for VBscript.

This is why I can not work directly with variables instead of strings:

There is a list of comma separated permission **names** which I get from a web service. The project manager may update this list any time and expects that I check if a user of software is granted to these permissions. User's permissions are set in run time by complex methods as well as profile data, history of activities in the software etc. e.g. if a user has bought 1000 products, the variable  SuperCustomerPermission will set for him in header of page using `SuperCustomerPermission="yes"` (not as cookies or session nor stored in a databse).

To check the list of permission I want to pass the list of permission **names** to a function and loop through the names:

Permission names which I get from a web service:

```
permissionNames = "adminPermission,deletePermission,configPermission,SuperCustomerPermission"
```

I try to pass these strings as variables to the subroutine:

```
Sub checkPermission(PermissionNames)
    permissionNamesArray = split(permissionNames,",",-1,1)
    For Each x In permissionNamesArray
        'How to convert x to its variable equivalent and check if it equals "yes"
    Next
End Sub

Call checkPermission(permissionNames)
```

Comment: Why do you think you need to call `checkPermission("adminPermission")` instead of calling `checkPermission(adminPermission)`? Where does that string come from? What is the actual problem you're trying to solve by doing this?

Comment: I added more details that why I can not work with variables instead of strings. @AnsgarWiechers

Comment: Aside from the fact that the `Array` function doesn't convert a comma-separated string to an array, you still haven't explained why you think you need to change permission name strings to variables of the same name. Please take two more steps back and describe the actual problem you're trying to solve instead of what you perceive as the solution. What are you trying to accomplish with these permissions/variables? Is `permissionNames` your reference (what you get from the DB), or is it what you want to compare against the reference?

Comment: I have edited entire the question. Please check again @AnsgarWiechers

Comment: Can you use a dictionary, as Jacob M. suggested (e.g. `permissions("SuperCustomerPermissions") = "yes"`)? Then you could simply check `permissions(x) = "yes"` in a loop. Otherwise you'd have to resort to `Eval` or `Execute`, which is not recommended.

Comment: Would you please post your answer using eval and execute? @AnsgarWiechers

Comment: No, I won't. Sorry, but I'm not going to help you shoot yourself in the foot.

Comment: https://weblogs.asp.net/alex_papadimoulis/408925

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it is possible to put it into application or session you could do something like `session(variableName) = 5`.

If not, the next easiest way is using a dictionary:

```
Dim myDict
Set myDict= CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
myDict.Add (variableName, value)
```

Comment: Dictionary object would be my first choice. I'm pretty sure you could also put a dictionary object inside a Session variable as well if you wanted to do that.

Comment: Thank you. I will redeem bounty if no one suggest better solution using `eval` or  `execute`.

Answer (score 1):

**Using a dictionary should work fine with your situation and it's much cleaner.**

That being said, since you asked for an `Execute` solution, you can do something like this:

```
Sub checkPermission(PermissionNames)
    Dim permissionNamesArray, x

    permissionNamesArray = split(permissionNames,",",-1,1)
    For Each x In permissionNamesArray
        Dim valueOfX
        Execute "valueOfX = " & x
        WScript.Echo valueOfX
    Next
End Sub
```

**Example of usage:**

```
' Adding some values to the variables
Dim adminPermission, deletePermission, configPermission, SuperCustomerPermission
adminPermission = "yes"
deletePermission = "no"
configPermission = "yes"
SuperCustomerPermission = "no"

' Storing names of variables
Dim permissionNames
permissionNames = "adminPermission,deletePermission,configPermission,SuperCustomerPermission"

' Passing variables by names
checkPermission(permissionNames)
```

**Output:**

> yes 
>   no 
>   yes 
>   no